# How can I change the font size of text in VS Code's Output panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can change the editor font size, and I can change the terminal font size. But I wonder if there is a way of changing the output font size?

[image]

I've tried to look at settings(UI) but couldn't find. I also did Google search but couldn't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output Channels can have an associated [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) (see `createOutputChannel(name: string, languageId?: string): OutputChannel` in [the extension API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)), but most of them use the other function overload, `createOutputChannel(name: string, options: {log: true}): LogOutputChannel`, which uses the specially defined ["log" language mode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/log). What you need to do is find out what language mode is being used in the output channels of interest, and then override the `editor.fontSize` setting just for those languages.

To handle the basic cases of the "log" language mode, try putting something akin to the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"[log][Log]": {
    "editor.fontSize": 14, // whatever value you want
}
```

You can add other language modes to the above list as needed. See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings.

Other related source code for the `log`/`Log` language mode IDs for when VS Code uses them can be found in relation to [src/vs/workbench/services/output/common/output.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/services/output/common/output.ts), where `OUTPUT_MODE_ID` and `LOG_MODE_ID` are defined. Also interesting is the fact that their language support extension defines `Log` as an alias of `log`, but they are registered separately in [src/vs/workbench/contrib/output/browser/output.contribution.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/output/browser/output.contribution.ts), which I think is why in my experience, you need to specify `"[log][Log]":` instead of just `"[log]":` in the language override setting.

Courtesy of https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91304.

Also related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176198 and https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/995.

Above issue tickets found by googling "`github vscode issues change output font size`".

Answer (score -3):

Click File > Preferences > Settings > Notebook>Output Font Size, you will see its value 0 as a default. Change it as your desire.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqXOY.png)

Comment: FYI - Tried this technique and didn't work for myself.  However answer from @starball worked just fine.

Comment: this is for Jupyter Notebook outputs... not the Output Panel as asked in the question