# Changing VS Code console 'output' font size only

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't seem to rly find console font size for 'Output' window ONLY. Every similar topic seems to be related to 'Terminal'/editor+output/VS Code UI (Zoom option) font size, but I can't get my way over this case.

Is there any way on modifying such value...?

EDIT: Still, after numerous tries, no attached solutions for changing explicitly the Log was successful. When a solution for the issue will be found, together/or with the root cause of `settings.json` not overriding my gui setup I'll mark it down in this topic.

Comment: @starball - apparently not in my case, no - I've seen these cases, and adding such key-value to my settings.json file in project in ./vscode does not do any change. Output font follows the editor font size. There is an option for ex. for changing separately such val. for Terminal, works fine, but this output tab is haunting me...

Comment: just edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75829017/11107541) please see the updated version and give it a try.